# passing moree than one value of slugs in taxonomy using variable

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-query

```
array(
  'taxonomy' => $taxonomy_array_value,          
  'field' => 'slug',
  'terms' => array( $term_name )
)
```

This is my code where `$taxonomy_array_value` and `$term_name` are variables coming from ajax.

**First Case :**
`$taxonomy_array_value = Colors` and `$term_name = 'red'` then `WP_Query` is working fine.

**Second Case :**
`$taxonomy_array_value = Colors` and `%term_name = 'red','green'` but in this case it's not working.

While instead of using variable if I direct pass 'red','green' in 'terms' then it's working fine but not working with variable Don't know why.

Here is my code from which I am getting $term_name

```
$term_name = "'" . implode("','", $term_value_array) . "'";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
'terms' => $term_value_array
```

instead of

```
'terms' => array( $term_name )
```

It looks like the problem is that you use `array("'red','green'")` instead of the array structure: `array('red','green')` that you want.

Comment: Thanks for answer and you know what I already did it before your answer and another thing that you answered in my one other question Thanks for that Thankyou so much.

Comment: great to hear it worked out for you, good luck with your project.